# Separate Chaining Hash Tables - When to stop looking

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, hashmap

Quick question about hash tables.
I'm currently implementing a hash table
using a combination of separate chaining
and open addressing, limiting the length
of each bucket's linked lists to a certain length.

However, I'm having trouble thinking of a way to efficiently get/remove
with this hash table structure, and am wondering if I'm being blindly stupid
or if anyone has approached a similar issue before.

If I try to continually probe using the collision resolution scheme, I could be potentially going forever and never finding out if the key is not in the table. This is because most probing methods will not cover every bucket, and I'd rather not use linear probing.

Because most probing methods will not cover every bucket, and it is expensive to keep track of which buckets you've looked at, if a bucket is emptied but a subsequent bucket in the probing path is not, the algorithm cannot simply stop once it encounters an empty bucket.

I'd greatly appreciate any ideas on the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: binary seach. If your database (hash-map) contains 1 million entries you only need ~20 search operation in average instead of 500.000. the only requirement is, that the map is sorted

Comment: I do realize the benefits of a good old binary search, but the map isn't sorted, and I was under the impression the whole point of hash maps was that they didn't have to be sorted (in the formal algorithm sense of the word) to get good performance

Answer (score 0):

In scenario like unlimited collision, we usually tend to use:

- linear probing: with n jumps each time, where n is a prime number >= 7, why prime? 90% of the hastables using prime number usually iterate over every cell in the table therefore traversing the whole table instead of just jumping around each cell.
- poly probling: with n jumps each time, where n is recomputed using a polynomial function such as f(x) = x^2 + 2x + 1, why? this gives a different result on each cell and isn't based of the values in the cell completely.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe I should change to linear probing then. I had been using "fibonacci probing," in which the probing progresses according to the fibonacci sequence in order to provide a different approach to the distribution of resolved collisions. Could I still possibly use this approach while being able to determine whether or not the table contains the key during get/remove without settling for O(n) time?